# Find the maximum likely estimator of $\frac{1}{\sigma^n}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{\sigma}}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Find the maximum likely estimator of $L(\sigma,\mu)=\frac{1}{\sigma^n}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{\sigma}}\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,X_{(1)}]}(\mu)$

We differentiate $L$ and equate to zero to find the critical points. We start by differentiating with respect to $\sigma$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L(\sigma, \mu)}{\partial\sigma}
   = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i-n\mu}{\sigma^{n+2}} e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{\sigma}} -\frac{n}{\sigma^{n+1}}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{\sigma}} = 0\Rightarrow \sigma = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{n}
\end{equation}

on the other hand if we differentiate with respect to $\mu$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L(\sigma, \mu)}{\partial\mu} = \frac{n}{\sigma^{n+1}}e^{-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\mu}{\sigma}}=0
\end{equation}

However, in the derivative with respect to $\mu$ I don't get to anything in particular.

Another argument I was thinking about was that since $L$ is increasing and differentiable we could assume that the maximum value for $\sigma$ is found for $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and for $\mu$ it is reaches at $\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, that is, the maximum likelihood estimator is $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$.

However, in the derivative with respect to $\mu$ I don't get to anything in particular.
Another argument I was thinking about was that since $L$ is increasing and differentiable we could assume that the maximum value for $\sigma$ is found for $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and for $\mu$ it is reaches at $\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, that is, the maximum likelihood estimator is $\left(X_{(1)},X_{(n)}\right)$.
Can someone help me know which way to go?

Comment: What is the domain of the $x_i$? You haven't provided it.

Comment: Yes, if $\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\mu}}>0$ then $L$ is increasing and the maximum is attained at $\max\{x_i\}$. Then the MLE is the random variable $\max\{X_i\}$

Comment: @Clarinetist ,ok i have updated it

Comment: What is $\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,X_{(1)}]}(\mu)$ about?

Comment: @Henry That is the indicator function: $1$ when $-\infty < \mu \leq X_{(1)}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Clarinetist So you are implicitly saying saying that the support for $X$ is $[\mu, \infty)$.  It might be worth mentioning that more explicitly as it will affect the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $\ln$, we have the log-likelihood $l(\sigma, \mu) = -n\ln(\sigma) -\frac{1}{\sigma} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - n\mu)$. Note that minimising $L$ is equivalent to minimising $l$. Hence, if $\tilde{\sigma}$, $\tilde{\mu}$ are the MLEs, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial l(\tilde{\sigma}, \tilde{\mu})}{\partial \sigma} &= -\frac{n}{\tilde{\sigma}} + \frac{1}{\tilde{\sigma}^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - n\tilde{\mu}) = 0\\
\implies \tilde{\sigma} &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - n\tilde{\mu})\\
\frac{\partial l(\tilde{\sigma}, \tilde{\mu})}{\partial \mu} &= \frac{n^2}{\tilde{\sigma}}
\end{align*}
Hence, $l$ is increasing in $\mu$, so it reaches its maximum at $\tilde{\mu} = X_{(1)}$. Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\sigma} &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - nX_{(1)})\\
\tilde{\mu} &= X_{(1)}
\end{align*}